# F# printfn anomaly

Tags: f#

Can anyone please explain why this results in an error:

```
let xs = [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]

Array.iter printfn xs
```

Whilst this does not:

```
Array.iter printfn [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]
```

Comment: In addition to pad's explanation: You can also fix this by changing the last line to `Array.iter (printfn "%s") [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]`.

Answer (score 7):

The signature of printfn is `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a`. The compiler infers literal values of strings as `Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>` but cannot do so with dynamic strings.

You can help the compiler in the first example by adding correct type annotation:

```
let xs: Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit> [] = [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]
Array.iter printfn xs
```

or using explicit constructors:

```
let xs = [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]
Array.iter (fun s -> printfn <| Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(s)) xs
```

In general, it's too verbose to do so. Therefore, specifying format strings such as `"%s"` for strings and `"%O"` for types overriding `ToString()` method is the good way to go:

```
let xs = [| "Mary"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]
Array.iter (printfn "%s") xs
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @pad's excellent answer.

The main reason for confusion is misunderstanding of what happens with the arguments. Let's look at single iteration. It supposed to be

```
printfn "%s" "Mary" // or whatever default format specifier instead of %s
```

but in fact, it is

```
printfn "Mary" ()
```

So `"Mary"` is not a string to be formatted. **It is a format specifier**, quite useless but well suitable for formatting a `unit`.

Try this modification to your sample:

```
Array.iter printfn [| "Mary %s"; "Mungo"; "Midge" |]
```

and it will refuse to compile.