# How Do I Use A Variable As The Formatting String With Sprintf?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I feel like a total noob for having to ask this but it's got me stumped.

I set a format string like this:

```
let fs = "This is my format test %s"
```

Then I attempt to use it like so:

```
let s = sprintf fs "testing"
```

When I do so I get this error:

```
//stdin(26,17): error FS0001: The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.StringFormat<('a -> 'b)>'
```

So I then tried this:

```
let s = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat fs) "test"
```

to which the REPL responded:

```
//stdin(28,18): error FS1124: Multiple types exist called 'StringFormat', taking different numbers of generic parameters. Provide a type instantiation to disambiguate the type resolution, e.g. 'StringFormat<_>'.
```

So I then tried this:

```
let s = sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<string> fs) "test"
```

And I get this:

```
//stdin(29,18): error FS0001: The type ''a -> 'b' does not match the type 'string'
```

Am I missing something painfully obvious? This is using F# 3.0 on the Mac from the Xamarin Studio F# Interactive Window.

Comment: `[<Literal>]` attribute is the answer. Also check existing questions on the topic: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551851/why-does-fs-printfn-work-with-literal-strings-but-not-values-of-type-string), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708229/f-printfn-anomaly)

Comment: In this particular application, I can't use [<Literal>] but I can see where you're going with that.  Thanks.

Comment: @bytebuster I tried adding a literal attribute but that doesn't seem to work.  Maybe you could hack together some code and post it as an answer?  I may be missing your intent.

Comment: There are two links in the comment above, my answer to the first one contains a code sample with `[Literal]`. Otherwise, please let us know more about "that doesn't seem to work".

Comment: @bytebuster See this gist https://gist.github.com/OnorioCatenacci/6923465 to see what I tried.  Perhaps I misunderstood how you meant to use the literal attribute in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So you actually need to create a `StringFormat` which has a function type as follows

```
> sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<string->string>("Hello %s")) "World";;
  val it : string = "Hello World"
```

In Section [6.3.16](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818841) of the spec, an example of this is shown.

Comment: Worked for me! This one has bugged me for years, and I've worked around it, but had to finally address it with a complex problem. Notes: 1. the function type `<string -> string>` will have as many types as there are format specifiers in the format string, plus the return type `string`, eg. ` ...<string -> int -> string -> string>("Hello %s, %d, %s")) "Jim" 17 "Bye".` 2. With that in place, the components can be built previously, with `let .. ` bindings. eg. `let formatStr = "Hello %s, %d"`.

Comment: Note 3. I tried to get around the unwieldy sequence of types, ie. `string -> int -> string -> string` with the technique in https://swlaschin.gitboo'ks.io/fsharpforfunandprofit/content/posts/printf.html, as follows: `let formatter : Printf.StringFormat<_> = "Hello, %s, %d, %s"`. This worked! However, it doesn't compile if the string literal is replaced with a variable, ie. `let formatter : Printf.StringFormat<_> = aFormatString`.

Comment: Note 4. The same technique can be used to build a variable as the format parameter to `printfn`, by replacing `Printf.StringFormat` with `Printf.TextWriterFormat` and changing the result type from `string` to `unit`, ie. `let formatter = Printf.TextWriterFormat<string->string->string->unit>(formatfixed) in printfn formatter "Jim" "4" "Bye"`.