# F# non-literal printf format strings - how to make them passable as parameters?

Tags: f#, printf

I would like to use non-literal strings for the "format" parameter of a logging type function, as shown here:

```
// You need to make c:\testDir or something similar to run this.....
//
let csvFile = @"c:\testDir\foo.csv"

open System.IO

let writer file (s:string) =
  use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file, true)
  streamWriter.WriteLine(s)
  // s

let log format = Printf.ksprintf (writer csvFile) format

let oneString format = (Printf.StringFormat<string->string> format)

let format = oneString "(this does not %s)"

//log format "important string"

log "this works %s" "important string"
```

My first attempt used a literal string, and the above fragment should work fine for you if you create the directory it needs or similar.

After discovering that you can't just "let bind" a format string, I then learned about `Printf.StringFormat`and more details about `Printf.ksprintf`, but I am obviously missing something, because I can't get them to work together with my small example.

If you comment out the last line and reinstate its predecessor, you will see a compiler error.

Making the function `writer` return a string almost helped (uncomment its last line), but that then makes `log` return a string (which means every call now needs an `ignore`).

I would like to know how to have my format strings dynamically settable within the type checked F# printf world!

**Update**
I added the parameter `format` to `log` to avoid a value restriction error that happens if `log` is not later called as it is in my example. I also change `fmt` to `format` in `oneString`.

**Update**

This is a different question from [this one](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202773/how-do-i-use-a-variable-as-the-formatting-string-with-sprintf). That question does not show a function argument being passed to `Printf.StringFormat` (a minor difference), and it does not have the part about `Printf.ksprintf` not taking a continuation function that returns unit.

I thought I had found a solution with:

```
let oneString format = (Printf.StringFormat<string->string,unit> format)
```

this compiles, but there is a runtime error. (The change is the `,unit`)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202773/how-do-i-use-a-variable-as-the-formatting-string-with-sprintf

Comment: your answer to that question helped me find `Printf.StringFormat`, but it does not explain why I need to uncomment the `//s` in `writer` to make things sort of work (I want `writer` to return `unit`). I suspect there is some type checking subtlety I am missing.

Comment: I messed around with this a little yesterday.  I think you will find it useful to add explicit type annotations to everything.  At some point I managed to actually get the code to compile and do what you asked for but on the second run I landed in a state that throws a run-time error.